# programacao em Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, relacionamento

Tenho um formulário e nele incluo uma tabela `médicos`, e nesta tabela tem um campo `enum` onde se pode escolher a opção de `cooperativa`, mas tenho que verificar em outra tabela de `cooperativa` se este médico possui uma `cooperativa`.

Na validação, como faço para ler estas duas tabelas e verificar se o `médico` possui uma `cooperativa`, pois caso contrario tenho que mostrar uma mensagem dizendo que este médico não possui `cooperativa`.

Comment: você utiliza qual banco de dados ?

Comment: sim , eu acesso atraves do active admin.

Comment: banco de dados mysql

Comment: necessita criar um join então, vou colocar como resposta para exemplificar, tente reproduzir no mysql e se der certo como quer já irá lhe ajudar

Comment: private
      def validate_presence_of_cooperatives
        errors.add("cooperative", "Deve Haver uma Cooperativa para este especiaista") if specialties.empty?
      end

Comment: Vc precisa mostrar pro usuário, no formulário, medicos que não tem nenhuma cooperativa associada? Porque, se não, vc no controller, ja faria algo como: @medicos = Medico.com_cooperativa. Dessa forma vc nao precisa se preocupar com a validação. Vc so faria um scope na model de medico que te retornaria uma coleção de medico que tem cooperativa